# Trying to make a grouped barplot and keep receiving "Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to make a grouped barplot using the barplot function in R, but I keep receiving the same error message.

Here is the matrix I am trying to plot:

```
               acer       carya        fagus       fraxinus    quercus     sassafras shade_intolerant
tally_hect_95 177500.0   45312.5       19687.5       0.0       101250.0      63125.0    32187.5   
tally_hect_19 654912.28  68070.18      15614.04 244736.84      270526.32    142105.26  165087.72
```

And here is my line of code (very simple):

```
barplot(seed2, beside=TRUE)
```

I want tally_hect_95 and tally_hect_19 to be grouped together with the species groups the grouping variable along the x-axis.

Does anyone see a problem with the data that I have? I don't understand why it will not work.

Thank you in advanced.